# knockout foreach beforeRemove animate anomaly : animate SOMETIMES applied to adjacent identical div

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-animate

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7z7kP/8/

The animation gets applied to the wrong card whenever two cards *of the same suit* are adjacent.  Why?  I cannot find my error, if I've made one.

```
   self.animateRemove = function(element,index,value){
             $(element).parent().find("div").eq(index).animate(
                 { height: 1, width: 1 }, 444, 
                    function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using primitive types (`string`) in your `hand` `ko.observableArray` and KO cannot properly detect which item was removed when you have clicked on a card because you have the same cards multiple times in the array. So KO chooses the last one.

To solve problem you need to use objects in your `hand` array instead of plain strings:

So modify your `addCard`:

```
self.addCard = function(data,event){    
    var imgbutton= $(event.currentTarget);         

    self.hand.push( { suit: imgbutton.data("suit") } );            
};
```

And your view:

```
<div id="hand-container" data-bind="foreach: {data: hand, 
     afterAdd: afterAdd, beforeRemove: animateRemove}">
    <div data-bind="text: suit"></div>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYZzG/).

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I am puzzled when you say that KO cannot detect which item was removed because I'm using primitive types. I used splice with an `index` when I removed the item from the observableArray:  `self.hand.splice(el.index(),1);`, so wouldn't KO at that point know the index? Or is KO comparing a before-remove-snapshot of the array with an after-remove-snapshot, to determine which item had been removed?

Comment: The self.hand.splice(el.index(),1) removes the correct item. But after that KO will compare the arrays and do some change tracking which items where removed/added/moved, - I don't know the exact details - so it essentially does a snapshot comparison that is why it confuses on the "same" elements.